# In JavaScript, why pass the context as an argument to a function call when the context is already determined by who calls it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, this

A read an article on Medium called

> You Must Understand These 14 JavaScript Functions by bitfish

In the article the author writes about functions a JavaScript developer must know or understand when/before a Job Interview - for position as a JavaScript developer.

In the examples there is a constant usage of passing in a context as an optional argument. Unfortunately the author does not go into details on why we would pass a context argument like here:

```
mappedArr[i] = fn.call(context, arr[i], i, this);
```

My question is "In JavaScript, why pass the context as an argument to a function call when the context is already determined by who calls it?"

Under what condition is it useful to have that context available (another context)?

Here is the code listed below:

```
let selfMap = function(fn, context) {

   let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
   let mappedArr = Array();
   for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {

     if (! arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

     let info = [];
     info.push({ "context" : context } );
     info.push({ "arr[i]" : arr[i] } );
     info.push({ "i" : i } );
     info.push({ "this" : this } );
     console.log(info);

     mappedArr[i] = fn.call(context, arr[i], i, this); 

   } 
   return mappedArr;

 };
```

And then call it using:

```
Array.prototype. selfMap = selfMap;
[1,2,3].myMap(n => n * 2);
```

Why would one provide a context as a second argument to myMap? I think there may be a JavaScript Design Pattern for this, but at this time I could not find any references, due to all the debris of search results on Google that are unrelated to my search.

I did write a function and passed in the context as a second argument but I am not sure, though I could come up with my own thoughts, what is the main reason for doing this?

Here is my example of using it:

```
[1,2,3].selfMap((n, o, p) => {

     let info = [];
     info.push({ "n" : n } );
     info.push({ "o" : o } );
     info.push({ "p" : p } );
     info.push({ "this" : this } );
     console.log(info)
     return n * 2;

});
```

Could pass this or window or {}

Context would be equal to the current context of where we called the method from

```
[1,2,3].selfMap((n, o, context) => {

         let info = [];
         info.push({ "n" : n } );
         info.push({ "o" : o } );
         info.push({ "context" : context } );
         info.push({ "this" : this } );
         console.log(info)
         return n * 2;

}, this);
```

Window as context argument

```
[1,2,3].selfMap((n, o, context) => {

     let info = [];
     info.push({ "n" : n } );
     info.push({ "o" : o } );
     info.push({ "context" : context } );
     info.push({ "this" : this } );
     console.log(info)
     return n * 2;

}, window);
```

And we could use a custom object

```
[1,2,3].selfMap((n, o, context) => {

     let info = [];
     info.push({ "n" : n } );
     info.push({ "o" : o } );
     info.push({ "context" : context } );
     info.push({ "this" : this } );
     console.log(info)
     return n * 2;

}, { something: 1 });
```

So, I know that a context can be passed, but I don't know why I might want to pass in a context.

Please with-in your answer provide not only an explanation but an example(s) to clarify your explanation.

**Thank You**

Comment: Javascript doesn't store `this` as part of function calls,.  It's implied, eg.  `obj.func`,.. JS knows the context here is `obj`, because of the dot notation.  But if you then did `var x = obj.func`, and called `x`, JS does not know what the context is because we have lost the dot notation.  In other languages like C#, method calls are made of  data & method ptrs, in JS we only pass around method ptr's, so content needs to be bound with JS if you want to pass it about, or alternative bind your `method ptr` with `call` or `bind`.. Hope that makes sense.. :)

Comment: When you invoke a JS function via `call()`, `this` inside the function body during call time will refer to whatever is passed in to it as `context`.

Answer (score 0):

There are situation in which the context (this) can be overshadow by the caller, but one might need to refer a different context altogether. In that case, it would be very helpful if you pass the context as argument.

Please consider the following example

```js
class DomManipulation() {
      
    constructor() {
      this.someValue = "someValue"

      this.registerEvent();
    }

    eventListener() {
      console.log(this);  // can you guess the context of this here 
      console.log(this.someValue); // answer is undefined. Since this is pointing to `#oneDomElement` dom here. so access to class DomManipulation variable is overshadowed 
    }

    registerEvent() {
      document.querySelector("#oneDomElement").addEventListener('click', this.eventListener);
    }
 }
```

```html
    <div id="oneDomElement">Hello</div>
```

As you can see in the above example, the value of `this` is over-shadowed by the Dom element since we have setup a listener for the click event. Now it not possible to access the `DomManipulation` class member variables (ie. someValue)

So, in-order to overcome the problem, we can do the following

```
eventListener(event, context) {
      console.log(this); // now this will point to DomManipulation class
      console.log(this.someValue);  // someValue
      // also 
      console.log(context) // you can also use DOM `#oneDomElement` context here 
}

registerEvent() {
       const self = this;
      document.querySelector("#oneDomElement").addEventListener('click',  (event) => {
           self.eventListener.call(self, event, this);
      });
}
```

With the above solution, you could access to both the context here, 
 1. `this` will point to `DomManipulation` class
 2.  `context` will point to the `#oneDomElement` DOM element.

Comment: Hi Prasana, thank you for the explanation. So what you have done in registerEvent is create a proxy to the DomManipulation instance, right ?

Comment: Is there a design pattern for this? Maybe proxy design pattern?

Comment: @Frank, well Ur right. It's kind of proxing. actually this works like a chained function where registering a arrow function in turns call our listener function. Yes metaphorical u can call this as proxy pattern. But most often people in JavaScript call this arrow function call widely.

Comment: @frank if you feel the explanation answer Ur question ?   Is it fine for you to mark the answer as correct ?